# How to refer properties file or excel file located in resources folder?

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7

I created a simple maven project. I placed one properties file and one xlsx file in `src/main/resources` folder. How can i load the properties/excel files? I tried as below.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/app.properties");
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It throws exception saying that properties file could not be located. Am i doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: getClass().getResourceAsStream("/app.properties");

Answer (score 1):

Take help of  ServletContext's `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()`.
Suppose you have the following folder structure `src/resources/images`

```
    String file1 = "images/filling.png";
    InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file1);

   String file2= "images/filling.png";
   InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(file2);
```

Comment: That will not work, cause the folder `src/main/resources` is automatically copied to target/classes which can be used by `getResourcesAsStream()`. So the part `resources` is wrong here.

Comment: If under resources image is a subfolder then 
String file1 = "images/filling.png";
InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file1); thats what you mean right?? @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet, you can get absolute path using getServletContext().getRealPath ("."), this will return you the absolute path, in it append remaining path till your resources folder and read the desired files using FileInputStream.